# Use Wayland on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wayland

Trying to use Wayland on Ubuntu 15.04, I followed the instructions I can find on google. I can see the gdm login screen and choose GNOME on Wayland shown as below. But after I type in my password it goes back to login screen again. I'm pretty sure I type in the right password.

I have tried both ona VM and my actual machine, they have the same result.

Any idea?

Platform: ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64

Instructions:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install xwayland weston
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-session-wayland
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Reference:

[How to Install Latest Wayland in Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome via PPA](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/04/latest-wayland-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/)

[Now You Can Easily Install And Test Wayland On Ubuntu 15.04 And Ubuntu 15.04 GNOME](http://linuxg.net/now-you-can-easily-install-and-test-wayland-on-ubuntu-15-04-and-ubuntu-15-04-gnome/)

[image]

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah, actually you're right. It probably should be renamed just wayland.

Answer (score 0):

see brute way:

Try Update first: https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/44def31e824d0b7a45fe14609738e696

The first link is to update the system to latest state.

and after install with dependencies: https://gist.github.com/wellington1993/1e3c2f7254b1a372c3158b15c125e3f7

The second is more detailed Way to install dependencies.

NOTICE: But I'm think the Wayland is for more updated Ubuntu and not recommend for versions below 17.10

Comment: I can't solve with this solution when tried to install in Linux Mint the Waylant environment.